# check which fonts are embedded in the final pdf

Tags: fonts, pdftex, pdf, embedding

One of the requirements I have from the publisher is to make sure all fonts are embedded into the pdf. I am using pdflatex to convert my .tex file into a pdf. How can I check to make sure all fonts are embedded? I am using Windows, MikTex 2.9.

I saw some answers about pdffonts utility but I don't have this in my distribution, I believe. It also doesn't come with Cygwin as I have that on my computer also.

Comment: Your PDF viewer can show you the fonts and, for each, whether it is embedded, embedded as a subset or not embedded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your PDF viewer can provide this information. Here are some font listings provided by Okular, for example.

[image: all embedded]

In this PDF, all fonts are fully embedded. This means that all characters from the font are included, even if they are not used in the document. Full embedding violates many commercial font licences and increases the size of the resulting PDF.

[image: embedded subsets]

Here, all fonts are embedded as subsets. This is what you should expect from pdfTeX in most cases. This means that all characters actually used in the document are included i.e. that subset of the font which is actually required to display the PDF are included. Characters not used in the document are omitted as they aren't required to display the document and just increase the size of the PDF for no benefit.

[image: non-embedded]

None of the fonts are embedded in this PDF, so Okular is substituting system fonts as best it can. Because I lack many of the fonts used by the document, `fontconfig` is substituting fonts I do have according to its configuration rules. For some reason, it thinks Noto Sans is a good substitute for almost everything, although I'm unclear why. I assume this is because it doesn't recognise all the font names (e.g. it knows Arial but not ArialMT). This is what you ***don't*** want as your document will ***not*** look the way you intended.

Comment: what does embedded as subset mean? how do i embed things fully (i think that's what i need?)

Comment: It is very unlikely they want full embedding. For one thing, this violates many commercial font licences. For another, it makes PDFs unnecessarily ginormous. Subsetting embeds all characters from the font actually used in the document. So, if you never use theta, it won't be included, even if the font provides it. Full embedding will include every character from the font, including ones you never use. If you do need full embedding, be sure to not load `microtype` or disable font expansion. This will help a bit with the size.

Comment: ok i have to check with them to understand if they want full or subset embedding (can't think of why anybody would need full based on what you just told me). just noticed one of the fonts is listed as F16, type 3. but it doesn't say anything next to it (the rest say embedded subset). does this mean it isn't embedded, and if so how do i fix that?

Comment: I've added a bit of explanation above. Originally, I think subsetting wasn't an option. So then there will have been a time when probably some viewers couldn't deal with it. But anything modern (even remotely modern) should be OK with it. But it is definitely always good to check. Do you know which font `F16` is? Are you using any fonts not available as type1?

Comment: are you available to continue this conversation in a quick chat?

Comment: Sure. If it is quick.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42682/discussion-between-alex-and-cfr).